# Urgent Installation Failed

Tags: magento2.2.3, php-7.2

The installation stops before starting with the Error message that "base table not found"

I have already added the table to the database and its there, but it keeps giving this message that Sales_shipment table not found. Help please, it's urgent!

```
[ERROR] PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'onlinestore.sales_shipment_item' doesn't exist in engine in C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(93): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SHOW INDEXES FR...', Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(541): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SHOW INDEXES FR...', Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(615): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SHOW INDEXES FR...', Array) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\DbSchemaReader.php(130): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('SHOW INDEXES FR...') #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\SchemaBuilder.php(80): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\DbSchemaReader->readIndexes('sales_shipment_...', 'default') #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\SchemaConfig.php(66): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\SchemaBuilder->build(Object(Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Schema)) #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\DeclarationInstaller.php(58): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\SchemaConfig->getDbConfig() #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(808): Magento\Setup\Model\DeclarationInstaller->installSchema(Array) #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(830): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->declarativeInstallSchema(Array) #13 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema(Array) #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(367): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #16 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #17 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #18 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #19 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #20 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #21 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #22 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #23 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #24 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #25 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #26 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\setup\index.php(39): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #27 {main} Next Zend_Db_Statement_Exception: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'onlinestore.sales_shipment_item' doesn't exist in engine, query was: SHOW INDEXES FROM sales_shipment_item WHERE `Non_unique` = 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:235 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(93): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SHOW INDEXES FR...', Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(541): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SHOW INDEXES FR...', Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(615): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_query('SHOW INDEXES FR...', Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\DbSchemaReader.php(130): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->query('SHOW INDEXES FR...') #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\SchemaBuilder.php(80): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\MySQL\DbSchemaReader->readIndexes('sales_shipment_...', 'default') #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\magento\framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\SchemaConfig.php(66): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Db\SchemaBuilder->build(Object(Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\Dto\Schema)) #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\DeclarationInstaller.php(58): Magento\Framework\Setup\Declaration\Schema\SchemaConfig->getDbConfig() #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(808): Magento\Setup\Model\DeclarationInstaller->installSchema(Array) #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(830): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->declarativeInstallSchema(Array) #12 [internal function]: Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installSchema(Array) #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Model\Installer.php(367): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\setup\src\Magento\Setup\Controller\Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array) #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction() #16 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #17 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #18 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #19 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Controller\AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #20 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response)) #21 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #22 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #23 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-eventmanager\src\EventManager.php(260): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure)) #24 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\vendor\zendframework\zend-mvc\src\Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent)) #25 C:\xampp\htdocs\Onlinestore\setup\index.php(39): Zend\Mvc\Application->run() #26 {main}
```

Comment: Your installed has some file missing.Download magento zip again

Comment: its my first time with magento, am i download again and just replace?